Execute and match once each if statements into a for loop using python
I have some if statements into a for loop; I need to find and eventually match once each if statement.
example:
From my database I have some horses with their running data;
I set some variables to find specific data, like this:
horses = "Showtime Mahomes (GB)"
courses = "Doncaster"
distances = "5f"
pos1 = "1"
pos2 = "2"

So, I need to find if these data matches with my database records, but doesn't matter if my data matches three times, I count just once.
I am trying to do it with a loop for with some if statements.
This is my code:
from typing import Generator
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import islice
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

horses = "Showtime Mahomes (GB)"
courses = "Doncaster"
distances = "5f"
pos1 = "1"
pos2 = "2"

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  password="",
  database="horseracinguk"
)


engine = create_engine('mysql://root@localhost/horseracinguk?')


mycursor = mydb.cursor(dictionary=True)

mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM mytable")

myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for row in myresult:
   if horses == row["horse"]:
     if ((courses == row["course"]) and (pos1 == row["pos"])):   
        pointscourse1 =+ 2

        horse = row["horse"]
        course = row["course"]
        distance = row["dist"]
        position = row["pos"]
        print(horse, course, distance, position, pointscourse1)
        break
     
     if ((courses == row["course"]) and (pos2 == row["pos"])):   
        pointscourse1 =+ 2

        horse = row["horse"]
        course = row["course"]
        distance = row["dist"]
        position = row["pos"]
        print(horse, course, distance, position, pointscourse1)
        break
     
     if ((distances == row["dist"]) and (pos1 == row["pos"])):   
        pointsdist1 =+ 3
        horse = row["horse"]
        course = row["course"]
        distance = row["dist"]
        position = row["pos"]
        print(horse, course, distance, position, pointsdist1)
        break
     

So, if my horse "Showtime Mahomes (GB)" has ran and arrived 1st, I got 3 points, but just once (doesn't matter if He did it three times, I count just one)
And so on...
I hope it's clear, sorry but I am a newbie of python
Thanks for your help
EDIT: This code doesn't work because it use just first IF STATEMTENT and don't use the others

If your code works, why are you here?  If it doesn't, explain what specific issue(s) you have with it.

@ScottHunter because doesn't work. it stopped just after first IF STATEMENT and don't use the others

You have break statements that are exiting your for loop. You should remove them if you want to parse the entire thing also your syntax for incrementing the score should be += not =+

I did, but it doesn't work, because it takes all with that values, but I want just one for each if statement
